# Did I actually just win 1 Ethereum? Is it truly mine?

Tags: accounts, bug, faucets, zero-knowledge, exchange-api

I was looking for coins to mine & exchange for bitcoins when I found out about Ethereum. I have literally no knowledge about it or anything at all. I went for a site (https://freeeth.me/) to win free Ethereum. I needed an account so I created one using metamask. I then played the game once, but it said I couldn't claim my prize because of an error in the API.

HOWEVER, this happened on my account:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xb1eab8d33cbeb30e242d3453afd1e3a6061d3ebc

Does that mean the site just deposited 1 Ethereum on my account? Because otherwise, I have NO CLUE where this came from. I created the account literally 10 minutes ago and I already have sixty dollars in cryptocurrency.

Comment: ropsten is a testnet. You won't be able to sell it.

Comment: So that means whatever I win are not really going to this address?

Comment: It is not real cryptocurrency. There is no value in the public. It is kind of ethereum network to work with blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, Ether **is** a real cryptocurrency. On Coinbase.com, 1 Ether can be exchanged for about $67 today. However, on the top of the page at the URL in your question, you will see **ROPSTEN (Revival) TESTNET**. ropsten is a test network, for developers to experiment with Ethereum and test their applications. So, the 1 Ether **did** go to your account but it is only play money. That is why you cannot get dollars for Ether you have on ropsten.